# Windows search suddenly not allowing typing

Tags: windows-10, start-menu

The problem is a bit difficult to describe, but the start menu search has suddenly started not allowing me to type more than a character or two. I can't even click the search bar and input more, it just immediately seems to tab back to the options it brings up. Has anyone else ever heard of this bug, or had a fix? It isn't debilitating, but it is extremely annoying.

Comment: What version of Windows 10 are you using.  Instead of submitting commentary you should edit your question to include this vital and necessary information.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

**First: DISM / SFC**

```
Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator.
dism.exe  /online  /cleanup-image  /startcomponentcleanup
dism.exe  /online  /cleanup-image  /restorehealth
SFC /SCANNOW
```

Restart when complete and test.

**Second: If that does not work (50:50 chance), run Windows 10 Repair install.**

> https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10
>
> Windows 10 is running, so click on the Download button (not Upgrade
> Button) and select Run. If the Repair will not run as per above, use
> the Download button to create a USB Windows Installation key, then run
> Setup on the USB Key.
>
> This will launch the Repair and proceed normally.
>
> Start with the option to Keep Everything.
>
> You can also Keep Data, or Keep Nothing. Keep Nothing is very close to
> a clean install.

Note: The above repairs cannot repair a damaged Windows 10 User Profile. If the User Profile is damaged, it needs to be replaced by saving all the data and email, deleting the profile and making a new one.

Answer (score 0):

you can using the Search and Indexing troubleshooter. It makes sure that the Windows Search service is running.

Go to `Control Panel`. In the search box, type troubleshooter, and then click Troubleshooting. Click View all, and then click `Search and Indexing`.